# Issue programming breadboarded Arduino via FTDI chip

Tags: uploading, breadboard

I am trying to upload the Blink sketch to my ATmega chip which is now on a breadboard connected via an FTDI chip.

My clock is running, power is OK. I connected the reset pin via a 100 kohm to the vcc and have a 0.1 uF capacitor between the reset pin and the DTR pin of my FTDI chip.

[image: a picture]
[image: a close up]

Connections to the PCB with the FTDI chip: 
[image: Connections to the PCB with the FTDI chip]

Does anybody know what I am doing incorrectly?

On a side note, I am running Ubuntu 16.04

All this seems correct to me, yet when I try to program the controller I get this exact:

```
/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware /home/yalishanda        /Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware -tools /home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/tools-builder -tools /home/yalishanda    /Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr -built-in-libraries /home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/libraries -libraries     /root/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10805 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_476404 -warnings=none -build-        cache /tmp/arduino_cache_889393 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr -verbose /home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/examples/01.Basics/Blink/Blink.ino
/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/arduino-builder -compile -logger=machine -hardware /home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware -tools /home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/tools-builder -tools /home/yalishanda    /Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr -built-in-libraries /home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/libraries -libraries /root/Arduino/libraries -fqbn=arduino:avr:uno -ide-version=10805 -build-path /tmp/arduino_build_476404 -warnings=none -build-cache /tmp/arduino_cache_889393 -prefs=build.warn_data_percentage=75 -prefs=runtime.tools.arduinoOTA.path=/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avrdude.path=/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr -prefs=runtime.tools.avr-gcc.path=/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware    /tools/avr -verbose /home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/examples/01.Basics/Blink/Blink.ino
Using board 'uno' from platform in folder: /home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr
Using core 'arduino' from platform in folder: /home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr
Detecting libraries used...
"/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-I/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino" "-I/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard" "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp" -o "/dev/null"
Generating function prototypes...
"/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics  -flto -w -x c++ -E -CC -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-I/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino" "-I/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard" "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp" -o "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/tools-builder/ctags/5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/preproc/ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compiling sketch...
"/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++" -c -g -Os -w -std=gnu++11 -fpermissive -fno-exceptions -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-threadsafe-statics -MMD -flto -mmcu=atmega328p -DF_CPU=16000000L -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_AVR_UNO -DARDUINO_ARCH_AVR   "-I/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino" "-I/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/arduino/avr/variants/standard" "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp" -o "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp.o"
Compiling libraries...
Compiling core...
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/wiring_pulse.S.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/WInterrupts.c.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/hooks.c.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/wiring.c.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/wiring_analog.c.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/wiring_digital.c.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/wiring_pulse.c.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/wiring_shift.c.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/CDC.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/HardwareSerial.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/HardwareSerial0.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/HardwareSerial1.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/HardwareSerial2.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/HardwareSerial3.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/IPAddress.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/PluggableUSB.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/Print.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/Stream.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/Tone.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/USBCore.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/WMath.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/WString.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/abi.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/main.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/new.cpp.o
Using previously compiled file: /tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/core.a
Archiving built core (caching) in: /tmp/arduino_cache_889393    /core/core_arduino_avr_uno_fbfa3aa7d5698fed1dc5326dc32eae8f.a
Linking everything together...
"/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-gcc" -w -Os -g -flto -fuse-linker-plugin -Wl,--gc-sections -mmcu=atmega328p  -o "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/Blink.ino.elf" "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/sketch/Blink.ino.cpp.o"     "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/core/core.a" "-L/tmp/arduino_build_476404" -lm
"/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -j .eeprom --set-section-flags=.eeprom=alloc,load --no-change-warnings --change-section-lma .eeprom=0  "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/Blink.ino.elf"     "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/Blink.ino.eep"
"/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy" -O ihex -R .eeprom      "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/Blink.ino.elf" "/tmp/arduino_build_476404/Blink.ino.hex"
Sketch uses 928 bytes (2%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 9 bytes (0%) of dynamic memory, leaving 2039 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.

/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -v -patmega328p -cstk500v1 -P/dev/ttyUSB0 -Uflash:w:/tmp/arduino_build_476404/Blink.ino.hex:i 

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 11:00:16
     Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
     Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

     System wide configuration file is "/home/yalishanda/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
     User configuration file is "/home/yalishanda/.avrduderc"
     User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

     Using Port                    : /dev/ttyUSB0
     Using Programmer              : stk500v1
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
...
```

Comment: Start with connecting all power pins. You've left `Vcc` on pin 20 and `GND` on pin 22 unconnected.

Comment: @KIIV ok, did that although I was not sure whether that was really necessary. Unfortunately it still doesn't work

Comment: Why it's showing `stk500v1` protocol instead of `arduino` for the `avrdude`?

Comment: @KIIV I don't know, I chose the following options in the arduino ide: "board: arduino/genuino UNO" "port:/dev/ttyUSB0" "programmer: AVR ISP" isn't that correct?

Comment: No, you should just upload the code. Just like it's UNO board.

Comment: @KIIV ok, I managed to upload it in a different way (upload it like if it were an arduino rather than going via sketch > upload using programmer): https://paste.ubuntu.com/26432421/

But that still doesn't work

Comment: And is that chip extracted from the UNO board or it's a new one (without the arduino bootloader)?

Comment: @KIIV it is a new one but it normally already should have a bootloader

Comment: @KIIV I can see the DTR line on the ftdi chip being low, for a short period being high and the low again. So I *think* the DTR line is doing its job. In other words the ATMEGA chip is *I think* correctly being reset.

Comment: Do you have a normal Arduino Uno board? You can swap out the chip there and see if you can program it. The board is guaranteed to have all the connections right. If it still fails, your ATMega328P has not been programmed with the Arduino Bootloader. You'll need another working Arduino or a ICSP programmer for that. Also: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5fvdxd0QhTw and https://www.baldengineer.com/diy-arduino-schematic-checklist.html might be good references for you.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I can't do that because the arduino uno I have uses a mcu in an smd package not through hole

Comment: There are only 3 possibilities: Wrong wireup (use above reference to check that), no bootloader on your chip, or chip is straight out dead. After you compared the wireup, I would still try to burn the Arduino bootloader to the chip. You can't destroy it further with that anyways. Try to follow https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VX0P8B3pk7g .

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt I am able to get the board info (Tools > get board info). Can I infer from that that the chip is alive and wiring is OK? And I am maybe unable to upload code due to a corrupt bootloader?

Comment: if you disconnect the avr chip, do you still get board info? (leave ftdi connected)

Comment: @LandonZeKepitelOfGreytBritn How do you know the chip should have a bootloader when new? Did you specifically buy one with a bootloader installed? They don't come from the factory like that.

Comment: @Majenko yes I specifically bought one with a bootloader

Answer (score 2):

Right now you don't have a bootloader on your chip that's the reason why it wouldn't be programmed via UART so to flash the bootloader you need an ISCP programmer and an arduino bootloader.hex file.

Answer (score -1):

10K reset pullup.
Check your crystal caps, they should be 22pF.

The response does look like the chip does not have a bootloader tho.
Or Rx & Tx lines are swapped.